# In MySQL, is it possible to have a UNIQUE constraint on a row?

Tags: mysql, unique

Appears that MySQL's UNIQUE constraint is on a columns by column basis, I'm looking for a way to make sure the row are UNIQUE on a row by row basis; guessing the answer is to create a hash from by concatenating the columns per row I want to be UNIQUE then but a UNIQUE on the column storing the hash for that row. Also, the rows themselves unless I create a control will always be UNIQUE, since the ID for the row is a SURROGATE_KEY; meaning it's an integer sequential growing by +1 of the ID of the last row's integer.

Comment: Performance would suck if there's a large number of fields, but you could just add a unique key with all fields listed in it. You'd have to exclude the ID field, though, since that would break the uniqueness you're wanting.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question -- you want to make sure rows are unique without using unique columns?  But aren't all table's rows unique due to the existence of primary keys?

Comment: @ryebr3ad: primary keys being unique only works if the key is natural, in the case it's not, it's an artificial generated sequential integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a multiple-column `UNIQUE` index.

Comment: The multiple-column UNIQUE appears to be just that, a UNIQUE on more than one column, not a UNIQUE on a combo of columns. Is that wrong?

Comment: wrong? In what sense? If you create a UNIQUE index on `(col1,col2)` then it will make sure, no two rows have exactly same values in both of these columns.

Answer (score 3):

The main ways to ensure a row is completely unique is to use the `UNIQUE` constraint on every column or create an analagous `UNIQUE` index on every column. If you can allow two columns to accept the same input but you need to uniquely distinguish them, there's no reason why you would need anything more than a primary key (basically an ID column). The other thing you could do is switch to a column-store database such as [InfiniDB](http://www.infinidb.org/), which has a MySQL front-end, or [MonetDB](http://www.monetdb.nl/), both of which are open source alternatives.

Comment: The primary key is UNIQUE, it's also an artificial generated sequential integer.